# UIView: Performance/memory difference between alpha:0, hidden:YES, removeViewFromSuperview and frame.origin.y = -100000;

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

What is best for the device when temporarily hiding a view (e.g. until loading is done)?

- Setting alpha to 0?
- Setting hidden to YES?
- Removing view from superview?
- Moving the view to a position which makes it not possible to be visible on window/screen (e.g. frame.origin.y = -10000)?

Which is best in terms of memory and which is best in terms of performance? I know Apple somewhere wrote something about this, but I can't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of UIView: removeFromSuperview VS hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328830/performance-of-uiview-removefromsuperview-vs-hide)

Comment: @James well, I consider it to not cover all alternatives

Comment: @James also, memory is just as relevant as performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Which is best in terms of memory**

`removeFromSuperview` is the best in term of memory. Why ? Because it will cause the view to be released. So if the view is not retained by anyone else (like a strong ivar), it will be deallocated.

**And which is best in terms of performance?**

`setHidden:` is the best in terms of performance. Why ? Because the action is just to set a flag. And then in drawRect it's just a BOOL check. So it's really fast because there is no other action involved.

Answer (score 3):

So, the fastest method first:

1. `setHidden` (discard view from rendering only)
2. `alpha` to `0` is Equal to `setHidden, but it first checks if`0`
3. `removeFromSuperView` (need some steps: deallocate object, pop from stack (pointer), remove from rendering stack...)
4. `frame.origin.y=-10000` > must move a whole bit array and check if the view comes out of bounds. not very fast...