# Difference between removeFromSuperview and .hidden for an imageview

Tags: ios, uiview

Is there a difference between `removeFromSuperview` and `.hidden`property for an imageview?

They both seem to just hide the imageview. I would like to completely remove the imageview under certain circumstances.

Comment: This is not specific to `UIImageView`. This applies to an `UIView` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of UIView: removeFromSuperview VS hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328830/performance-of-uiview-removefromsuperview-vs-hide)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**removeFromSuperview**

1. Removes the object from its parent view, thus 'hiding' it in a sense.
2. Removes any constraints tying the view to its parent view or other sibling views
3. Implicitly removes the retain count of a view, potentially causing an object to be deallocated if nothing else has a reference to the object

**hidden**

1. Makes the view hidden
2. The view is still part of layout

Answer (score 2):

Hidden makes the view hidden/untouchable - it's akin to making the alpha equal to 0.

removeFromSuperview removes the view completely from its superview.

The two are pretty different, so it really depends on what you want. If you plan on temporarily hiding the view, then making it hidden is probably what you want. If you want to remove it and have no plans on adding it again (at least within the view controller's lifecycle), then removeFromSuperview is better.

Comment: alpha equal to 0 still renders the view in each pass, it is not the same as setting it as hidden, you can check this with the Xcode UI debugger... it is a great tool to tell how much are you drawing despite the fact of having things with alpa equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

To complete remove image view from your view. You should use `removeFromSuperview`.
By calling this method removes any constraints that refer to the view you are removing, or that refer to any view in the subtree of the view you are removing.

Nevertheless a hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and participates in autoresizing as usual.

From my experience i recommend to remove view by `removeFromSuperview`.