# What's the best way to present different modes in one UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to implement a screen that lists the data I receive from an API. There is a `mode` navigation bar button which changes how the data is displayed in the same screen (same view controller)

Added a gif at the end to make it easy to visualize. The concept I have is quite similar, but transition animation is not needed.

The task itself is pretty trivial, but I can't decide what's the best way to handle this "mode switch". I came up with below options.

**Option 1**: Having 2 different view controllers for each mode. `ContainerVC` holds a state, and changes childVC when mode is switched. I think this is the best approach when the data is different - such as in segmented control. Since the data used in both child view controllers are same in my case, it may be problematic to manage this.

**Option 2**: We have 2 different views for each mode (for example tableView - mapView) and we add/remove these subviews based on selected mode in same view controller. With this approach, my view controller can easily be massive and impossible to maintain in a heartbeat

**Option 3**: Similar to option 2, but instead of add/remove we show/hide one of the views.

I am not sure if there are other approaches that provides a cleaner way to solve this problem, and I'd be happy to read resources/documentation to read you share

[image: switch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the position of the views changes you could just update the constraints. If the views are totally different depending on the mode, I would definitely use a container view controller instead of hiding / showing the views for performance reasons. You can store the two view controllers (each of which manages a view for a single mode) in a container property, when the mode changes the container toggles the visible clild (removes the current child and its view, then places the other view controller in the hierarchy). I suggest you to store the data only in the container, then you can pass a container reference to the children (maybe during initialization), so children can access the same model data through the container, this avoids repetition or conflict.

Otherwise you could also use a single view controller with a method that is called when the mode changes. In that method you can simply remove the current views (not just hide them) and insert the others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you mind sharing a resource that validates this performance reasons claim of yours 

"I would definitely use a container view controller instead of hiding / showing the views for performance reasons"

Comment: @mamba4ever No problem for the answer. If you hide a view instead of removing it from the hierarchy, it will still involve the drawing system, if there are many hidden views this can affect performance, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328830/performance-of-uiview-removefromsuperview-vs-hide). Secondly the view persists in memory. I suggest you try your method and see if the UI is smooth (most likely, at least if many views are not involved).